# Database driven content printing its full DB string to page when no code told to do so?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm just making a newsfeed that is database driven, right now I have it working, but at the end of every news post, I get a string like so:

```
 21   <div id='newsfeed'>
 22     <%= @news.each do |new| %>
 23       <div class='span10'>
 24         <h3><%= new.title %></h3>
 25         <p class='muted'><%= new.date %></p>
 26         <p><%= new.body %></p>
 27       </div>
 28     <% end %>
 29   </div>
 30 </div>
```

and then my controller has this:

```
def home
    @news = Newsfeed.all
end
```

Yet the output looks like this:

[image]

It would work great if it didn't post the entire array, I'm not sure why it would.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use "silent"

```
<% @news.each do |new| %>
```

instead of

```
<%= @news.each do |new| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the equals sign on line 22:

```
 21   <div id='newsfeed'>
 22     <% @news.each do |new| %>
 23       <div class='span10'>
 24         <h3><%= new.title %></h3>
 25         <p class='muted'><%= new.date %></p>
 26         <p><%= new.body %></p>
 27       </div>
 28     <% end %>
 29   </div>
 30 </div>
```