# select specific attributes from array rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
     acts_as_voteable
 end
```

and Vote model

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base

 scope :for_voter, lambda { |*args| where(["voter_id = ? AND voter_type = ?", args.first.id, args.first.class.name]) }
  scope :for_voteable, lambda { |*args| where(["voteable_id = ? AND voteable_type = ?", args.first.id, args.first.class.name]) }
 scope :recent, lambda { |*args| where(["created_at > ?", (args.first || 2.weeks.ago)]) }
 scope :descending, order("created_at DESC")

  belongs_to :voteable, :counter_cache=>true,:polymorphic => true,:touch=>true
   belongs_to :voter, :polymorphic => true

  attr_accessible :vote, :voter, :voteable


 # Comment out the line below to allow multiple votes per user.
 validates_uniqueness_of :voteable_id, :scope => [:voteable_type, :voter_type, :voter_id]

end
```

when I get the post voters with these method

```
  <% @post.voters_who_voted.each do |voter|%>
  <%= voter.name %>
   <% end %>
```

I load my database
how can I select only the user name and user id from these array?

update I changed my code I am using thumbs_up gem I pasted less code first to simplify the question

Comment: A voter can be any user (not just the user to whom the post belongs?)

Comment: the user is the voter who voted for the post

Comment: updated answer. Take a look at source code of this gem. It can be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "load database"? If you want to select only id and name columns, then use `@post.users.select([:id, :name]).each ...`

Or is it about [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844467/database-driven-content-printing-its-full-db-string-to-page-when-no-code-told-to/) (according to code that you provided)?

UPD.

`voters_who_voted` loads all voters and returns array https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up/blob/master/lib/acts_as_voteable.rb#L113. You have to add own association to `Post` model:

```
has_many :voters, :through => :votes, :source => :voter, :source_type => 'User'
```

It's just example, perhaps `voters` will clash with already existing method, if any.

Then use it here instead of `voters_who_voted`

Comment: sorry it was a typo also select method with your code gives me ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)

Comment: Seems like @post.users is returning array instead of ActiveRecord::Relation object. Maybe it has already been loaded before? You should check your controller code and view code above this part or post it here

Comment: your method gives me ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationPolymorphicSourceError: Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Post#voters' on the po
lymorphic object 'Voter#voter'.

Answer (score 1):

did you try collect method ??

```
names = @post.users.collect(&:name)

ids = @post.user.collect(&:id)
```

If you want it to be related you can make a HASH with it. Id's mapped to the names.

Comment: Use `@post.users.pluck(:name)` in this situation

Comment: i guess the difference is pluck directly queries only that particular field and collect will collect from the whole row of data. having @post.users in a variable and collecting will make only one query to the db instead of two , since we need name and id.